# wrong title for personal website using Google search

Tags: google-search, react-js, next.js

I created a personal website using `next.js` and it is hosted on Vercel. I bought the domains using Vercel. The website shows correctly if I visit it.

My problem is that if I look up my name using Google, the website I created is listed, but using the wrong short title. How can I enforce that short title to be the one I want?